# Site specific font override in browsers?

Tags: browser, fonts

Is it possible to have the firefox browser (or chrome) use font overrides on particular web pages?

To be specific, I'm trying to look for a way to make all the wikipedia pages display in sans-serif instead of sans.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to override the fonts in Wikipedia specifically, edit [Special:MyPage/vector.css](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:MyPage/vector.css) (for the default Vector skin):

Example:

```
#bodyContent {
    font-family: serif;
}
```

This is stored in your Wikipedia account and works for all browsers. If you are using a different skin (theme), change the `.css` name (e.g. `monobook.css`).

(I assume you meant to write *"display in serif instead of sans"*, because "sans" and "sans-serif" are the same thing.)

Example for a specific font: `font-family: Garamond, "Times New Roman", serif;`

---

For a more general solution, install the *<del>Stylish</del>* *Stylus* extension for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/styl-us/) or [Chrome](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne). (In Firefox, you can manually edit [`userContent.css`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/UserChrome.css).) This way you can set overrides for specific sites, or for everything.

Example for Wikipedia:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
@-moz-document url-prefix(http://en.wikipedia.org/) {
    #bodyContent {
        font-family: serif;
    }
}
```

It's mostly the same as above, but with added `@namespace`, and wrapped inside an `@-moz-document` block.

Comment: Stylish (well, at least on Firefox, can't comment on Chrome but I'd assume so) can be used on a site-by-site bases as well as universally.

Comment: That's just awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You can creat an account with  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&type=signup&returnto=Special:Search) and  and upload your own css or select from a given list , some of which have san-serif fonts as default (myskin,nostalgia,simple,standard)

Answer (score 2):

See grawity's answer. Otherwise,

In firefox got to tools>options>content>font>advanced settings and disallow websites to choose their own fonts.